# Use jndi to lookup credentials to the 3rd party systems

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi, credentials

In our current application we need to store secure connection information (credentials) to other 3rd party systems. I know that in general it's not a good idea but I don't see any good alternatioves to store secure information
Our env is pretty standard java env: Linux + Tomcat(as application server). 
Just traversed to several different solutions and came up that probably the better solution just to store sensitive information in Tomcat JNDI resources.
Any better ideas how to cope with such task  (also it'd nice to have a good arguments on it)?

Comment: Why not just use a DB?

Comment: I really don't see any good arguments to store(not encrypted) credentials in DB. Would you see any benefits ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Tomcat JNDI resources"? These things that can be defined in server.xml ?

Comment: Use it like JNDI resources: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html